# why I got an error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to make join using LINQ command in Method syntax but I got this error :

An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

This is the controller which throw the error :

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            sample_details[] sampleDet = _context.sample_details.ToArray();
            int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
            var samples = _context.hospital_programs.Where(x => x.hospital_id == UserId).ToList()
                .Join(sampleDet , hosp => hosp.sample_id , sam => sam.sample_id , (hosp,sam) => hosp.sample_id);
            return View(samples);
            
        }
```

and the error in the join :

```
var samples = _context.hospital_programs.Where(x => x.hospital_id == UserId).ToList()
                .Join(sampleDet , hosp => hosp.sample_id , sam => sam.sample_id , (hosp,sam) => hosp.sample_id);
```

see the image no details is the join correct ?

[image]
how to solve this error please ?

Comment: So did you look at the InnerException details property? What  does it say?

Comment: @steve see the image no details is the join correct ?

Comment: If there is an inner exception you won't see it in that dialog. Catch the Exception and look at it in the debugger like you would for any other variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use this LINQ Query. Always place join before where clause

```
var person = (from hosp in _context.hospital_programs
              join sam in _context.sampleDet
              on hosp.sample_id equals sam.sample_id
              where hosp.hospital_id == UserId).ToList();
```